# How to get Laravel Auth Policies working with API Controller, and Form Requests

Tags: php, laravel

I have a boilerplate Laravel 9 app, with a model generated with the cli command `php artisan make:model Post -a --api` to make an API controller, with form request and policies.

The [Laravel Policy Authorisation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#creating-policies) docs doesn't seem to make it clear what to do with both a Policy and FormRequest. Do I call the policy class inside the FormRequest? Or ignore the policies for store/update?

How do I use auth policies with FormRequests for my API controller?

Answer (score 2):

Although its not told directly in the docs. You can use the policy inside the `authorize()` method in a `Form Request` :

[Authorization Using Model](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#via-the-user-model)

```
class UpdatePostRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize() : bool
    {
        return $this->user()->can(
            'update', $this->post
        );
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class PostController
{
    public function update(UpdatePostRequest $request, Post $post)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

So Instead of using `$this->authorize('update', $post)` inside the controller you can directly put it inside the `FormRequest`.

Hope it helps : )

Comment: That would mean the auth code either repeats in policy and form requests, or is separated into two files. There was a SO on why use form request when there's policies. To me, I wanted to keep everything in a single file to easily maintain/see where things are located.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by *auth code either repeats in policy and form requests* ?

Answer (score -1):

Docs didn't make it clear, posting incase anyone else is struggling. Example for User model, UserPolicy and UserController.

**First**, add the Policy class in AuthServiceProvider.

```
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider

    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];
```

**Second**, use authorizeResources in the controller to auto map policies to the api controller. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#authorizing-resource-controllers) for what the policy -> controller maps to

```
// App\Http\Controllers\UserController

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreUserRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUserRequest;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create the controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Sets up user policy for this controller
        $this->authorizeResource(User::class, 'user');
    }
...
}
```

**Last**, **DELETE** the authorize section from the FormRequests

```
// App\Http\Requests\UpdateUserRequest

class UpdateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    // DELETE the auth part below, otherwise it'd mess up using policies. 
    // I'm pretty sure this takes precedence over policies
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    //public function authorize()
    //{
        //return true;
    //}
}
```

Now the policies set in UserPolicy will be used as auth guards for the User Controller.